# External module not loaded in Erlang

Tags: erlang, rebar3

I am new here in [Erlang](http://www.erlang.org/). I am trying to load library which is hosted on git through [rebar3](https://www.rebar3.org/) and been able to compile successfully. Now when I try to run my Erlang application call the main function which actually points to library module function it throws an error in shell `'module could not be loaded'`.

I have tried `code.get_path()` but in that my module is not listed. So I am confused here. Can anyone help me out here ?

```
    ** Generic server <0.80.0> terminating 
** Last message in was {'DOWN',#Ref<0.1535589919.2261778436.90425>,process,
                               <0.79.0>,normal}
** When Server state == {st_tcprx,<0.79.0>,
                                  #Ref<0.1535589919.2261778436.90425>,
                                  #Port<0.612>,<0.79.0>,<<>>,true,undefined}
** Reason for termination == 
** {'module could not be loaded',
       [{smpp34pdu,pack,[0,2147483647,{unbind}],[]},
        {smpp34_tcprx,terminate,2,
            [{file,
                 "/home/antarix/IdeaProjects/smpp34/_build/default/lib/smpp34/src/mod/smpp34_tcprx.erl"},
             {line,69}]},
        {gen_server,try_terminate,3,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,648}]},
        {gen_server,terminate,10,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,833}]},
        {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]}
** exception error: no match of right hand side value 
                    {'EXIT',
                        {{undef,
                             [{smpp34pdu,pack,
                                  [0,1,
                                   {bind_transceiver,"simple","simple123",[],
                                       52,0,0,[]}],
                                  []},
                              {smpp34_tx,handle_call,3,
                                  [{file,
                                       "/home/antarix/IdeaProjects/smpp34/_build/default/lib/smpp34/src/mod/smpp34_tx.erl"},
                                   {line,54}]},
                              {gen_server,try_handle_call,4,
                                  [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,636}]},
                              {gen_server,handle_msg,6,
                                  [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,665}]},
                              {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                                  [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]},
                         {gen_server,call,
                             [<0.77.0>,
                              {send,0,
                                  {bind_transceiver,"simple","simple123",[],
                                      52,0,0,[]}}]}}}
     in function  smpp34module:start/0 (/home/antarix/IdeaProjects/smpp34/_build/default/lib/smpp34/src/smpp34module.erl, line 43)
```

Here is my `code:get_path()` output

```
    code:get_path().
["/home/antarix/IdeaProjects/smpp34",
 "/home/antarix/IdeaProjects/smpp34/_build/default/lib/smpp34/ebin",
 ".","/usr/lib/erlang/lib/kernel-5.3.1/ebin",
 "/usr/lib/erlang/lib/stdlib-3.4.1/ebin",
 "/usr/lib/erlang/lib/xmerl-1.3.15/ebin",
 "/usr/lib/erlang/lib/wx-1.8.1/ebin",
 "/usr/lib/erlang/lib/tools-2.10.1/ebin",
 "/usr/lib/erlang/lib/syntax_tools-2.1.2/ebin",
 "/usr/lib/erlang/lib/ssl-8.2/ebin",
 "/usr/lib/erlang/lib/ssh-4.5.1/ebin",
 "/usr/lib/erlang/lib/snmp-5.2.6/ebin",
 "/usr/lib/erlang/lib/sasl-3.0.4/ebin",
 "/usr/lib/erlang/lib/runtime_tools-1.12.1/ebin",
 "/usr/lib/erlang/lib/reltool-0.7.4/ebin",
 "/usr/lib/erlang/lib/public_key-1.4.1/ebin",
 "/usr/lib/erlang/lib/parsetools-2.1.5/ebin",
 "/usr/lib/erlang/lib/otp_mibs-1.1.1/ebin",
 "/usr/lib/erlang/lib/os_mon-2.4.2/ebin",
 "/usr/lib/erlang/lib/orber-3.8.3/ebin",
 "/usr/lib/erlang/lib/odbc-2.12/ebin",
 "/usr/lib/erlang/lib/observer-2.4/ebin",
 "/usr/lib/erlang/lib/mnesia-4.15/ebin",
 "/usr/lib/erlang/lib/megaco-3.18.2/ebin",
 "/usr/lib/erlang/lib/jinterface-1.8/ebin",
 "/usr/lib/erlang/lib/inets-6.4/ebin",
 "/usr/lib/erlang/lib/ic-4.4.2/ebin",
 "/usr/lib/erlang/lib/hipe-3.16/ebin",
 [...]|...]
```

> Note : I am using [Intellij](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) for writing my code

Comment: Can you verify that you have `smpp34pdu.beam` compiled in `_build/default/lib/smpp34/bin/`? And you say that "module is not listed", but `code:get_path` only list directories, so is there `_build/default/lib/smpp34/bin/` listed?

Comment: `smpp34pdu.beam` is compiled in `_build/default/lib/smpp34pdu/ebin` here `smpp34pdu` is my remote lib from git

Comment: Could you edit your question and add return of `code:get_path`?

Comment: you said that smpp34pdu.beam is in _build/default/lib/smpp34pdu/ebin but i saw that your path is _build/default/lib/smpp34/ebin ??? Can you recheck it?

Comment: yes correct has 2 folder generated `_build/default/lib/smpp34` and `_build/default/lib/smpp34pdu` also `smpp34pdu` is not shown in `code:get_path()`

Comment: It looks like you are pooling `smpp34pdu` in incorrect manner.  Did you added it to your project deps, or just downloaded "manualy"?

Comment: added this deps `{smpp34pdu, {git, "link to my git repo", {branch, "demo"}}}` and it downloads properly in `_build/default/lib/smpp34pdu/ebin`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are pooling `smpp34pdu` in incorrect manner.  It should be as dependency to `smpp34`, but for some reason it isn't.  Easiest solution would be adding `smpp34pdu` to your deps in `reber.config`.

[smpp34](https://github.com/essiene/smpp34) is also seven years old library, and you might expect some incompatibility issues with rebar3, and/or current version of Erlang (if you are using one).  I would recommend cloning both repositories to your own GithHub account and fixing/adressing all issues you encounter.  You could upgrade config to rebar3, and add `smpp34pdu` as dependency to `smpp34`.

Comment: I have already added `smpp34pdu` as deps in `rebar.config` of `smpp34`